# Dealing with 404 error in spotify API - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, exception

I'm working with a dataset that has 5000 Spotify albums, my goal is to get the features from all albums. I'm having the following problem: Some lines of the file return an error like the one below:

```
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/search with Params: {'q': 'album:ニンテンドーDS ポケモン ダイヤモンド&パール スーパーミュージックコレクション (Nintendo DS Pokémon Diamond & Pearl Super Music Collection)', 'limit': 10, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'album', 'market': None} returned 404 due to Not found.
```

I'm searching for a "lazy" solution to this, there is some way to skip the error? I tried to use the except block:

```
for album_1 in all_albums:
    try:
        rows.append(merge_info(album_1))
    except:
        continue
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.